# How to use openlayers getUrl function in new ImageWMS?

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers in my reactjs project. As per the [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_ImageWMS-ImageWMS.html)

I have tried the following code

```
var sourceData = new ImageWMS(
      {
         params: {'LAYERS': 'top:states'},
         ratio: 1,
         serverType: 'geoserver',
         getURL: function () {
          console.log('bounds');
          }
      });



this.olmap = new Map({
      target: null,
      layers: [new ImageLayer({
          extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
          source: sourceData
        })],
      view: new View({
        center: this.state.center,
        zoom: this.state.zoom
      })
    });
```

I am trying the above code but it is not showing console log. 
Can I know how to make it work so that I can get the console log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply returns the url used to construct the source, e.g.

```
var sourceData = new ImageWMS(
      {
         url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
         params: {'LAYERS': 'top:states'},
         ratio: 1,
         serverType: 'geoserver'
      });

console.log(sourceData.getURL());  // 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms'
```

To log the full url or its query string parameters you would need to customise the imageLoadFunction

```
var sourceData = new ImageWMS(
      {
         url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
         params: {'LAYERS': 'top:states'},
         ratio: 1,
         serverType: 'geoserver',
         imageLoadFunction: function(image, src) {
           var params = new URLSearchParams(src.slice(src.indexOf('?')));
           console.log('bounds', params.get('BBOX'));
           image.getImage().src = src;
         }
      });
```